# How to change or view gtk.ListStore flags in Python

Tags: python, pygtk, treemodel

I have a TreeView connected with a ListStore object. One of the function calls ListStore.get_iter_next(). Since the ListStore data changes every time, I am doubtful that iter is causing a memory leak.

I need to check if the ListStore has gtk.TREE_MODEL_ITERS_PERSIST flag set and unset it as described in [TreeModel.get_flags()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html#method-gtktreemodel--get-flags) documentation.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you would just use bitwise operations on it - for example:

```
>>> a = 3 # just some number
>>> format(a, 'b') # display as a bit string so we can see what's going on
'11'
>>> a & 1 # check first bit is set
1
>>> a & 2 # check second bit is set
2 
>>> a ^= 1 # unset a bit
>>> format(a, 'b') # display for checking again...
'10'
```

Except you would use `gtk.TREE_MODEL_ITERS_PERSIST` instead... whether this is the right approach to your problem - I'm not sure - but answers your direct question as to how you could unset it.

Comment: What I mean is how exactly I set the flag? I am expecting something like store.set_flag(store.currentFlags ^ gtk.TREE_MODEL_ITERS_PERSIST). But I could not find such a function.

Comment: @Kashif Ummm - it's possible you're not meant to - you could look at the attribute that `get_flags()` returns and modify it directly - but at this point - I would be thinking you're *definitely* not meant to...

Comment: Documentation for `get_flags()` says it is a set of flags supported by ListStore